# Java Stream Api - good ways to operate on Map<String, Double>?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collect

I want to do some calculations with weighted averages. There are two maps

```
Map<String, Double> weightedVector;
Map<String, Double> otherVector;
```

The pseudo algorithm is like this

```
foreach entry in weightedVector:
  get same entry from otherVector 
  - if it exists then multiply weights and add new entry to another map
  - otherwise do nothing
```

I want to take advantage of the Stream API and came up with this

```
Stream<Double> map = weightedVector.entrySet().parallelStream()
.map(entry -> {
    Double t = otherVector.get(entry.getKey());
    Double v = entry.getValue();
    return (t != null && v != null) 
            ? t * v 
            : 0.0;
});
```

One question I ask myself whether it is good practice to use the old-style in order to access `otherVector` like in the snippet above.

The main problem for me is that I have two input maps and want to get an output map of the same type but the code above gets me a `Stream` of `Double` from the calculation.

Am I better off using `stream().collect(..)`, then how?

Is it maybe better to not use the `HashMap` but rather create a container object containing the key-value pair and use that instead?

Comment: So, do you want to do nothing when no entry is found in the other map (as your description says), or do you want to store 0.0 (as your code suggests)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you actually want to do nothing when there is no corresponding entry:

```
Map<String, Double> result = 
        weightedVector.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .filter(e -> otherVector.containsKey(e.getKey()))
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                          Map.Entry::getKey,
                          e -> e.getValue() * otherVector.get(e.getKey())));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify the map in-place then you could also loop over the `otherVector` entries and update the `weightedVector` map accordingly:

```
otherVector.forEach((key, t) -> weightedVector.computeIfPresent(key, (k, v) -> t * v));
```

This will compute the product of the `otherVector` and `weightedVector` values for each key in `otherVector`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, this is a good solution for large vectors where copying the memory all the time might be a trade-off.